# python: convert two strings of h & m into 24 hour time format

Tags: python, date, methods, time, module

I have a method which takes two variables:

- Current Time
- Minutes

The method is pretty simple. The user inputs the two values, the first being a string eg. '23:01'
The second being an integer eg 50. So the method calculates the new time by adding the two together, so the new time should be 23:51. 
I get  this to work, however when the time becomes  24:01 + 60 it becomes 25:01 which is an incorrect time. 
How do I simply use the time method in python to add the times?
Here is my code so far which throws up an error

```
import time
class timeCalc(object):
    def nextTime(self, time, minutes):
        t = time.split(':')
        mins = int(t[0]) * 60 + int(t[1]) + minutes
        h = str(mins/60)
        m = str(mins%60)
        if len(h) == 1:
            h = '0' + h
        if len(m) == 1:
            m = '0' + m
        nTime = time.strptime(h + ':' + m, "%H:%M")
        print nTime

ts = timeCalc()
ts.nextTime('23:01',60)
```

Comment: No need to use a class here, you have no state to maintain. You mask the `time` module with a local variable `time`, so your code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need parse the time parameter on that way, you can do:

```
Import datetime
class timeCalc(object):
    def nextTime(self, time, minutestoadd):
        base_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
        minutesobj = datetime.timedelta(minutes = minutestoadd)
        newtime = basetime + minutesobj
        print newtime.time()
```

Line 4:
You format the 'time' parameter to a datetime object with format %H:%M called base_time
Line 5:
You convert the minutestoadd parameter to a compatible object format to add 
Line 6:
The sum of both datetime object values
Line 7:
Print the result on a format like 23:40:00

Comment: I dont want to display the seconds? how do I do that

Comment: Replace print newtime.time() with print newtime.strftime('%H:%M')

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def nextTime(time, minutes):
    return (datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M') + timedelta(minutes=minutes)).time()

nextTime('23:01', 60)
```

returns `datetime.time(0, 1)` which can be printed:

```
nextTime('23:01', 60).strftime('%H:%M')
```

and returns `00:01`

Answer (score 0):

```
time.localtime(currenttime + 45 * 60))
```

IOT leave your job sooner try this